# Reactive-Extensions / RxJS Implementatation to node.js

Tags: node.js, reactive-extensions-js, rxjs

I simply want to implement

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

to my node project.

Surely, there is the npm-package available, but I see it less updated, less modules, and uses only min. files, so I want to use rxjs from git sources.

I downloaded RxJS-master and copy the whole files under the Dir to ../myProject/lib/rx/

I see

**rx.node.js** among those files

```
var Rx = require('./rx');
require('./rx.aggregates');
require('./rx.binding');
require('./rx.coincidence');
require('./rx.experimental');
require('./rx.joinpatterns');
require('./rx.testing');
require('./rx.time');
module.exports = Rx;
```

so, **my app.js** code is like this

```
var rx = require("./lib/rx/rx.node.js")

function test()
{
    var as = new rx.AsyncSubject()
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        as.onNext("works!")
        as.onCompleted()
    }, 500)
    return as
}

var a = test().subscribe(function (result)
{
    console.log("Got result: " + result)
})
```

This gives an error as follows,

```
.../rx/lib/rx/rx.binding.js:173
    var BehaviorSubject = Rx.BehaviorSubject = (function (_super) {
                          ^
ReferenceError: Rx is not defined
    at .../rx/lib/rx/rx.binding.js:173:27
    at Observable (.../rx/lib/rx/rx.binding.js:14:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../rx/lib/rx/rx.binding.js:18:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../rx/lib/rx/rx.node.js:3:1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is wrong?

---

If I modify
**rx.node.js** to

```
var Rx = require('./rx');
module.exports = Rx;
```

The code works as expected, so obviously *require* - *sub modules* section does not go well.

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed as of the latest build and I removed the bad build in question with [this commit](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/commit/19471ad947a08be1d3927a9a9325aa1432c0d034)

NPM has been updated accordingly to remove 2.1.1 and replaced with a non-broken version.

Comment: Thank you Mattew for quick response!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with the build that you are running, which I assume is 2.1.1. I had the same problem and the following npm commands fixed it for me.

```
npm remove rx
npm install rx@2.1.0
```

EDIT: I see you are using master. Sorry for the confusion. This solution might work for others that are running 2.1.1.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this. If this command:

```
$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

You can do this:

```
$ npm remove rx
$ npm install -g rx
```

If you don´t have nothing for "which npm" it can you must to remove node with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x#11178106)(the best answer) and reinstall with brew (with MacOS) or your package manager:

```
$ brew update
$ brew uninstall node
$ brew install node
```

and it can you must to use this:

```
$ brew postinstall node
```

According to the discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3125).